What is the 3-dimensional (and higher) versions of angles and angle measure?
An angle is the union of two noncollinear rays with a common endpoint. I wonder, is there an analogue of angles and angle measure in 3d and higher spaces? If so, what is the formal definition of that notion?

Yes, there are analogues to angles in higher-dimensional spaces, including 3D and beyond. In 3D space, the concept of an angle between two non-collinear rays extends to the angle between two vectors. More generally, in higher-dimensional spaces, we use concepts from linear algebra and geometry to define angles between vectors and planes.
Angle Between Two Vectors in 3D Space
In 3D space, the angle $ \theta $ between two vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $ can be found using the dot product formula:
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{u}\| \|\mathbf{v}\|}
$$
where:

$ \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} $ is the dot product of the vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $.
$ \|\mathbf{u}\| $ and $ \|\mathbf{v}\| $ are the magnitudes (lengths) of the vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $, respectively.

Angle Between Two Planes in 3D Space
For the angle between two planes, you use the normal vectors to the planes. If $ \mathbf{n}_1 $ and $ \mathbf{n}_2 $ are the normal vectors to the two planes, then the angle $ \theta $ between the planes is:
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{n}_1 \cdot \mathbf{n}_2}{\|\mathbf{n}_1\| \|\mathbf{n}_2\|}
$$
Generalization to Higher Dimensions
In higher dimensions (more than 3), the concept of angle between vectors is similar. The angle $ \theta $ between two vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $ in $ n $-dimensional space is given by:
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{u}\| \|\mathbf{v}\|}
$$
Angle Between Two Subspaces
In higher dimensions, we can also talk about the angle between two subspaces. For example, the angle between two planes in 3D is a special case of the angle between two subspaces in general. The formal definition involves the concept of principal angles or singular value decomposition, which extends to higher-dimensional spaces.
Formal Definition in Terms of Scalar Products
In any $ n $-dimensional Euclidean space, given two vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $, the angle $ \theta $ between them is defined by the scalar product (dot product) formula:
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{u}\| \|\mathbf{v}\|}
$$
This definition generalizes to higher dimensions and remains consistent with the notion of angles in 2D and 3D spaces.
Do these angles have different names?
Yes, in higher-dimensional spaces, angles between vectors or subspaces are often referred to using specific terminology, though the term "angle" itself is commonly used. Here are some relevant names and concepts:

Angle Between Vectors:

In any $n $-dimensional Euclidean space, the angle between two vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $ is simply called the angle between vectors. It is computed using the dot product formula:
$$
 \cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{u}\| \|\mathbf{v}\|}
 $$



Principal Angles:

When dealing with the angle between two subspaces, especially in higher-dimensional spaces, the concept of principal angles (or canonical angles) is used. These angles are the angles between the orthonormal bases of the two subspaces. Principal angles are particularly useful in applications such as dimensionality reduction and data analysis.


Geodesic Distance:

In more abstract spaces or on curved surfaces (manifolds), the angle might be generalized to the geodesic distance between points or subspaces, though this is more of a generalization beyond the typical Euclidean context.


Angle Between Hyperplanes:

In the context of hyperplanes (generalizations of planes in higher dimensions), the angle between two hyperplanes is defined using the normal vectors of these hyperplanes. This is similar to the angle between planes in 3D space.


Singular Value Decomposition (SVD):

When studying the angle between subspaces in terms of matrix decompositions, the singular value decomposition can be used. The angles between subspaces can be extracted from the singular values of a matrix that describes the relationship between the subspaces.



Summary
While "angle" is the general term used, in higher-dimensional spaces, the angle between vectors is often referred to simply as the angle between vectors, and the angle between subspaces involves concepts like principal angles.
In summary, while the intuitive concept of an angle between two rays or lines in 2D or 3D space can be extended to higher-dimensional spaces, the formal definition uses dot products and magnitudes of vectors to generalize the idea of angle to any dimensionality.
